# Subquery to return 1 result so results remain distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.title,
       a.section,
       a.name,
       l.User AS CreatedBy,
       IIf(IsNull(l.Time),
             Null, DateAdd ( "s", l.time, #03/01/1980# )) AS CreatedAt
FROM (
       Reports AS a
       LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS l ON a.ID = l.ID
     ) 
     LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT TOP 1 Min([time]) AS Mintime,
       URN FROM AuditLog GROUP BY ID)
      AS t ON (l.time = t.mintime) AND (l.ID = t.ID)
WHERE a.Active = 'Y';
```

The query works, but returns duplicate records (because there are multiple auditlogs for 1 Report). I would only like this to return one `ID` record showing the earliest audit time (thus what `mintime` is). I added the `TOP 1` but that did not seem to change anything. I've also considered `GROUP BY ID` but a bit confused about how to still show `title` etc, since it complains about them not being aggregate.

Current output:

```
ID         title        section     CreatedBy     CreatedAt
Z.test1    Example 1    Ex          User1         01/01/2012
Z.test5    Example 5    Ex          User2         02/03/2012
Z.test6    Example 6    Ex          User3         03/06/2012
Z.test6    Example 6    Ex          User4         02/01/2000
```

Expected output:

```
ID         title        section     CreatedBy     CreatedAt
Z.test1    Example 1    Ex          User1         01/01/2012
Z.test5    Example 5    Ex          User2         02/03/2012
Z.test6    Example 6    Ex          User4         02/01/2000
```

As shown above, only the earliest record for Z.test6 is shown and not all results.

Attempted new query:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.title, a.section, a.name, l.User AS CreatedBy,   IIf(IsNull(l.Time), Null, DateAdd ( "s", l.time, #03/01/1980# )) AS CreatedAt
FROM (
              Reports AS a 
LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT ID, Min([time]) AS Mintime FROM AuditLog GROUP BY ID
                  )  AS t ON (l.ID = t.ID)
              LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS l ON (a.ID = l.ID AND t.mintime = l.time)
)
WHERE a.Active = 'Y'
```

Comment: When using group by you must specify all columns that don't have an aggregate function applied to them.

Comment: @invertedSpear I did try that, but it still produced duplicate records on ID.

Comment: This part is why you still have all times even with the min: (l.time = t.mintime).  You probably want to inner join t to l, or eliminate the l part and inner join a to t, but I'm not entirely sure what the correct output is from this description so I'm not sure which way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the join order and only select the bare-minimum required fields in the subquery 't' that you need for grouping. Something like this:

```
SELECT a.ID,
   a.title,
   a.section,
   a.name,
   l.User AS CreatedBy,
   IIf(IsNull(l.Time),
         Null, DateAdd ( "s", l.time, #03/01/1980# )) AS CreatedAt
FROM (
   Reports AS a
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, Min([time]) AS Mintime
              FROM AuditLog GROUP BY ID) AS t 
     ON (a.ID = t.ID)
   LEFT JOIN AuditLog AS l 
     ON (t.ID = l.ID AND t.mintime = l.time)
 ) 
WHERE a.Active = 'Y';
```

Comment: That gives me `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '(l.time = t.mintime) AND (l.URN = t.URN) LEFT JOIN` ....

Comment: Where did the `AND (l.URN = t.URN)` come from?  It's not in my code ;)  Can you clarify what the `URN` field does, so I can determine how/if it should be used here?

Comment: Sorry, URN is ID. I forgot to transpose from my field names.

Comment: OK, so `Reports.ID` matches `AuditLog.URN` - is that it?  Updated query to reflect this.

Comment: All URN values are ID. URN is what it is called on my side, but in terms of this question it would be ID.

Comment: Can you post your current query (after the modifications I proposed) so I can see where it's going wrong?  Something isn't right about this...

Comment: Edited that into the question

Comment: `AS t ON (l.time = t.mintime) AND (l.ID = t.ID)` is incorrect.  It should be: `AS t ON (a.ID = t.ID)`.  The `AS l ON ...` specification is also not as I proposed, but it should work as you have it.

Comment: I fixed that incorrect part, but it's still giving a syntax error. Doesn't Access require extra parenthesis? I'm trying a few things.

Comment: @JBurace: remove the extra closing parenthesis ')' before the WHERE clause.